# How do I stop the UV map from changing while adding bevels?

Tags: uv

Im uv mapping a simple block, and I want to make it so the Square UV map stays and just wraps around the bevels. I will post pictures to show you what I mean.

[image]

I want it to keep the square UV map when I add the bevels, and I want the square part to just wrap around the bevels.

[image]

But when I add bevels, it messes up the uv map. I just want it to stay the same.

Comment: By definition UV map is based on the mesh so if you modify the mesh, you modify the UV map. One way to achieve what you want it to create 2 meshes, one low poly with the UVMap you want and the high poly version with the bevel and bake the high poly normals map onto the low poly UV map

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you used 3 segments. UV interpolation will be much better for an even number of segments.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you are beveling an edge with a seam on it. Since beveling creates multiple edges from a single edge, blender has to place the seam somewhere, yet there is no 'right' edge to place the seam on, so it gets applied to both created edges (extra segments do not receive a seam). What that means is that you will have to do some manual adjustments to make this work how you want. I would suggest removing the seam first, then beveling, then re-adding the seam where you want it. An alternative is to remove the seams after you have beveled the edges, but that will probably be a bit harder to do.